# AttributeError while running Meld from terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu, meld

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I get an `AttributeError` while running meld from terminal:

```
$ meld file1.txt file2.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
/usr/bin/meld:126: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed gtk.icon_theme_get_default().append_search_path(meld.paths.icon_dir())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/meld", line 126, in <module>
    gtk.icon_theme_get_default().append_search_path(meld.paths.icon_dir())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append_search_path'
```

What is this error and how can I correct this?

Comment: try to run meld with sudo "sudo meld"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start `xming` and then run `meld` command.